# Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler Scale in multiples of 3

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-scaling, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, horizontalpodautoscaler

We want our deployment to have 3/6/9/etc replicas at all times to have an even AZ spread.
Is there a way to achieve this via HPA config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Scaling policy with the **HPA**

**Example**

```
scaleUp:
    stabilizationWindowSeconds: 0
    policies:
    - type: Pods
      value: 3
      periodSeconds: 5
    selectPolicy: Max
```

it will add the **3** PODs every **5** second until HPA metrics become steady.

Ref doc : https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-autoscaling/853-configurable-hpa-scale-velocity/README.md